# How we can detect that VPN is connected in android or iOS using react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Is there any package we can use to detect 'VPN is connected in mobile'?
Or We can make a code to detect a vpn?

I will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this lib [react-native-vpn-detect](https://github.com/kzlsnn/react-native-vpn-detect)